# When I read an email on my iPad I am not receiving it on my laptop - how do I sync them?

Tags: iphone, ipad, data-synchronization

I am using YAHOO email on my MacBook Pro and my iPad and iPhone - but when  I open an email on my iPad it is not showing up on my laptop or iPhone. How do I get all of my emails on all of my devices?

Also - when I send a message via my iPad it also is not syncing to my other devices, so when a friend replies, it shows on my iPad but not my iPhone.

Comment: https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html

Answer (score 2):

In order to have your email sync on multiple devices, make sure your account is set up to use the IMAP protocol. Most free services, like Yahoo!, are set to use POP by default, which does not sync.

Go to your Yahoo! account settings at yahoo.com and change it to use the protocol to IMAP. You will have to then delete/change the email account on your iPad, and set it up as IMAP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the iPad email client is configured to automatically remove email from the server once read.

Check the mail account settings on the iPad and make sure 'Delete from server' is set to never.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my iPhone and HP laptop.  To correct it I went to settings and removed the "important conversations" label.  The feature allowed Gmail to present what it believed to important conversations which for some reason filtered out what I could see on my laptop.